# Getting error in Eclipse: syntax error on token start identifier expected

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting a strange error while creating a simple thread program in JAVA using Eclipse. The code is:

```
package threadshow;

public class Thread_Show extends Thread{

public void run(){
    System.out.println("Inside the thread");
}
 }

 class Thread_Definition{
Thread_Show ts=new Thread_Show();
ts.start();  //Getting the error here
}
```

I am getting error "syntax error on token start identifier expected" in the line `ts.start();`. Why am I getting this?

**EDIT** I have used the code from http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html#thread-subclass

Comment: Where is the method invocation? In the middle of a class definition?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I did not get you properly. As you see I am learning now..it will be easier for me if you expand on your comment.

Comment: The tutorial does not have that code directly inside a class body.

Comment: Which method should I invoke and where?

Comment: [Go through proper tutorials first](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). Learn the Java basics before you move to multi-threading.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I am sorry but I have to disagree with you. Instead of clearing which method I should invoke, you cited another tutorial and changed the discussion. I am still pointless about which method you are talking about. I know how methods work.

Comment: [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6) about what is allowed in a class body. You can't execute code directly like `ts.start()` in the class body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a very bad mistake done my me. Forgot to add `public static void main(String args[])` in the Thread_Definition class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't start your method inside class. Create some method first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining both of your classes in the same java file?. If so, you define both the classes in different java files naming Thread_show and Thread_definition. Then inside Thread_definition you can create an object of Thread_show and call its function.

Answer (score 0):

```
ADD main method-public static void main(String[] args) 

package threadshow;

public class Thread_Show extends Thread
{
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Inside the thread");
}
}

 class Thread_Definition
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Thread_Show ts=new Thread_Show();
ts.start();  
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.